# Any standard mechanism for detecting if a JavaScript is executing as a WebWorker?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

A WebWorker executes with a scope completely separate from the 'window' context of traditional JavaScript.  Is there a standard way for a script to determine if it is, itself, being executed as a WebWorker?

The first 'hack' I can think of would be to detect if there is a 'window' property in the scope of the worker.  If absent, this might mean we are executing as a WebWorker.

Additional options would be to detect properties not present in a standard 'window' context.  For Chrome 14, this list currently includes:

```
FileReaderSync
FileException
WorkerLocation
importScripts
openDatabaseSync
webkitRequestFileSystemSync
webkitResolveLocalFileSystemSyncURL
```

Detecting WorkerLocation seems like a viable candidate, but this still feels a bit hackish.  Is there a better way?

EDIT: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PS2VV/) is the JSFiddle I used to determine properties present in the executing WebWorker that are now in 'window'.

Comment: Why can't you just check for `window`?

Comment: How about `!(typeof window == "object" && typeof document == "object" && window.document === document)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#apis-available-to-workers) says:

> The DOM APIs (Node objects, Document objects, etc) are not available to workers in this version of this specification.

This suggests checking for the absence of `document` is a good way to check you're in a worker.  Alternatively you could try checking for the presence of [`WorkerGlobalScope`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#the-global-scope)?

Answer (score 5):

Although post a bit old, adding a couple of generic alternatives 
What is used in [Asynchronous.js](https://github.com/foo123/asynchronous.js) library (a library for generic handling of asynchronous/parallel processes, author) is the following:

```
// other declarations here
,isNode = ("undefined" !== typeof global) && ('[object global]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(global))
// http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_cluster
,isNodeProcess = isNode && !!process.env.NODE_UNIQUE_ID
,isWebWorker = !isNode && ('undefined' !== typeof WorkerGlobalScope) && ("function" === typeof importScripts) && (navigator instanceof WorkerNavigator)
,isBrowser = !isNode && !isWebWorker && ("undefined" !== typeof navigator) && ("undefined" !== typeof document)
,isBrowserWindow = isBrowser && !!window.opener
,isAMD = "function" === typeof( define ) && define.amd
,supportsMultiThread = isNode || "function" === typeof Worker
,isThread = isNodeProcess || isWebWorker
// rest declarations here..
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
  if (self.document) {
    console.log('We are calculating Primes in Main Thread');
  } else {
    console.log('We are calculating Primes in Worker Thread');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
if (self instanceof Window) {
    // not in worker
}
```

Comment: But it throws in a worker where both `self` and `Window` are undefined?

Comment: Oh, you're right, but `Window` is still `undefined` and `instanceof` will throw because of that.

Comment: @Bergi, Yea it will throw an error. Could continue from there though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I didn't see this method.

'navigator' exists in both Workers and Windows but the type names are 'WorkerNavigator' and 'Navigator' respectively.

```js
// true in Worker, SharedWorker, and ServiceWorker
// false in Window
const inWorker = navigator.constructor.name === 'WorkerNavigator';
```

As others have mentioned it, is a common practice to add fake objects to the global scope (like document) to fool scripts into thinking they are running in a Window scope. The type name for 'navigator' is very unlikely to be changed because navigator already exists in all scopes.

Answer (score -1):

There's even more: `WorkerNavigator` etc.

Unless there's a keyword to detect webworkers, you got to use a variable.
(Nothing can stop a rogue script running before your script from setting or replacing variables. )

So, assuming you do not have any rogue scripts running before your script, any of these lines will work:

```
this.DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope?this.__proto__ === this.DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.prototype:false

this.WorkerGlobalScope?this.__proto__.__proto__ === this.WorkerGlobalScope.prototype:false // works for shared workers too

this.constructor === this.DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope //or SharedWorkerGlobalScope

!(this.DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope === undefined)

!(this.DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope === undefined)
```

You can also use `self` [§](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/self) instead of `this`, but since `this` can't be set, its neater.

---

I prefer:

```
this.DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope !== undefined
```

---

Of course, if you only have worker context and window context, you can do the inverse tests for window context. Eg `this.Window === undefined`.

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated `__proto__`. Use either `Object.getPrototypeOf()`, or just `.isPrototypeOf` or `instanceof`.