# Reliably detect if the script is executing in a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am currently writing a little library in JavaScript to help me delegate to a web-worker some heavy computation .

For some reasons (mainly for the ability to debug in the UI thread and then run the same code in a worker) I'd like to detect if the script is currently running in a worker or in the UI thread.

I'm not a seasoned JavaScript developper and I would like to ensure that the following function will reliably detect if I'm in a worker or not :

```
function testenv() {
    try{
        if (importScripts) {
            postMessage("I think I'm in a worker actually.");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
            console.log("I'm the UI thread.");
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

So, does it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted there is an answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507638/is-there-a-standard-mechanism-for-detecting-if-a-javascript-is-executing-as-a-we) which says to check for the presence of a document object on the window.  I wanted to however make a modification to your code to avoid doing a try/catch block which [slows execution of JS in Chrome](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw&feature=player_detailpage#t=1602s) and likely in other browsers as well.

EDIT: I made an error previously in assuming there was a window object in the global scope. I usually add

```
//This is likely SharedWorkerContext or DedicatedWorkerContext
window=this;
```

to the top of my worker loader script this allows all functions that use window feature detection to not blow up.  Then you may use the function below.

```
function testEnv() {
  if (window.document === undefined) {
    postMessage("I'm fairly confident I'm a webworker");
  } else {
    console.log("I'm fairly confident I'm in the renderer thread");
  }
}
```

Alternatively without the window assignment as long as its at top level scope.

```
var self = this;
function() {
  if(self.document === undefined) {
    postMessage("I'm fairly confident I'm a webworker");
  } else {
    console.log("I'm fairly confident I'm in the renderer thread");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for point the fact that a try/catch should be avoided. As it's for a toy game engine I code, speed is an emportant aspect to me.

Comment: Note that 'self' is actually available by default in web workers https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: @JamiePate, `this` works too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45657328/632951

Comment: " I wanted to however make a modification to your code to avoid doing a try/catch block which slows execution of JS in Chrome "  Worst reason I have ever heard to change some code. With all due respect but this is the definition of premature optimization. There is *nothing* wrong with try..catch. Also there is *no* reason to cache loop variables and there are a hundred more premature optimization patterns that you should not fall into. Use try catch. It will *not* hurt your performance.

Comment: if it's at the top of your code (before any variables could be defined), you can just test `typeof window == 'undefined'`. This will be `true` in the UI thread and `false` in a worker thread. And it seems like a safe bet it will stay that way.

Answer (score 56):

Quite late to the game on this one, but here's the best, most bulletproofy way I could come up with:

```
// run this in global scope of window or worker. since window.self = window, we're ok
if (typeof WorkerGlobalScope !== 'undefined' && self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope) {
    // huzzah! a worker!
} else {
    // I'm not a worker... sad trombone.
}
```

Comment: Would: if (self.WorkerGlobalScope) {} else {} work as well? As long as no one has added WorkerGlobalScope to the project... seems effective and concise.

Comment: Yes you can, but I went with the double check because it's more reliable than hoping someone wouldn't write over `self.WorkerGlobalScope` (which admittedly is generally unlikely, but I prefer to default to more bulletproof)

Comment: works for me: self instanceof Window

Comment: This answer is much more accurate than the accepted one but "I'm a window" is only true if a Window exists. This is not the case for shells like d8.

Comment: yes, but that's a comment - so the `else` case could be `"I'm a meat popsicle"`. All it really means is `"I'm not a worker"`

Comment: Works on UWP Windows 10 JavaScript app.Just fyi to whomsoever concerned.

Comment: @borbulon, **There's no such thing as bulletproof.** If a rogue script runs before you, this function can always fail. Just use the most simplest option that works, that's perfection. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45657328/632951

Comment: @Pacerier do you just enjoy being pedantic? Of course there's no such thing as bulletproof. I said bulletproof-ish. As in, you can't get bulletproof but this is as close as you can get. If you're not going to add something of value to the conversation, take it elsewhere.

Comment: Still I have to agree with @Pacerier, at least with the *use the simplest option that works'. I'm not such a fan of 'someone might have redefined X' as a reason to double and triple check everything. Someone might have... but do you know what I am SURE of? That bandwidth is expensive and slow and you are wasting it 'just in case'.

Answer (score 16):

Emscripten does:

```
// *** Environment setup code ***
var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE = typeof process === 'object' && typeof require === 'function';
var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB = typeof window === 'object';
var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER = typeof importScripts === 'function';
var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL = !ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB && !ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE && !ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;
```

([Emscripten on Github](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/54b0f19d9e8130de16053b0915d114c346c99f17/src/shell.js))

Comment: You may also want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33697246/304175) by @NikosM to see what Asynchronous.js does.

Comment: But if you use -s MODULARIZE , then those ENVIRONMENT_IS_* variables are inside the module creation function and not visible to other code, right?